# Next.JS Esbuild JSX -> JS Code Transform within App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, esbuild

I'm currently using esbuild-wasm in my React frontend app. I've been converting it to a Next.JS app and am having trouble getting esbuild-wasm working since it keeps complaining that

`Error: The "wasmURL" option only works in the browser`

This used to work when I was on create-react-app but now with next-js I'm assuming it's in the Node context and no longer works.

I'd like to convert react code from jsx -> pure JS and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do so?

The basic context here is that I am looking to dynamically transform the code and render the transformed code in an iframe.

My setup is that I have a next_app where the esbuild.wasm is server under next_app/public.

Is there another way to do this?